# Mongoose not updating database with findByIdAndUpdate?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update my database using `findByIdAndUpdate` through an HTML form, which works for all but the nested data (`ePIMS`, `codeVersion`, and `region` all update with no problem). When I do `console.log(req.body.environment.instance)`, it outputs the data I typed in like it's going through correctly, but for some reason the mongoDB does not update with the information. Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?

mongoose schema:

```js
var environmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ePIMS: String,
    codeVersion: String,
    region: String,
    /*instance and testEnv don't seem to update in the database*/
    HCHC: {
      instance: String,
      testEnv: String
    }
  });
```

form I'm using to update:

```html
    <form action="/environments/<%= environment._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="environment[ePIMS]" placeholder="ePIMS" value="<%= environment.ePIMS %>" />
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="environment[region]" placeholder="Region" value="<%= environment.region %>" />

        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="environment[instance]" placeholder="HCHC Instance" value="<%= environment.instance %>" />
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="environment[testEnv]" placeholder="Test Environment" value="<%= environment.testEnv %>" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

edit and update routes:

```js
//Edit environment route
  router.get("/environments/:id/edit", function(req, res){
      Environment.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundEnvironment){
          if(err){
              res.redirect("/");
          } else {
              res.render("edit", {environment: foundEnvironment});
          }
      });
  });

  //Update environment route
router.put("/environments/:id", function(req, res){
  Environment.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.environment, function(err, updatedEnvironment){
    if (err) {
      res.redirect("/environments");
    } else {
      res.redirect("/environments");
      //console.log(req.body.environment.instance)
    }
  });
});
```

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**
Thank you Nayan for your help!

I changed the update route like so:

```
 //Update environment route
router.put("/environments/:id", function(req, res){
  var data = {
    HCHC : {
      instance: req.body.instance,
      testEnv: req.body.testEnv
    }
  }
  Environment.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: data}, function(err, updatedEnvironment){
    if (err) {
      res.redirect("/environments");
    } else {
      res.redirect("/environments");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `req.params.id` comes as string whereas `_id` in your database might be `ObjectId`. Can you try: `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)` ?

Comment: @mickl do you mean console.log it or try it in place of ```req.params.id``` ?

Comment: Try to replace `req.params.id` to convert the value to `ObjectId`

Comment: @mickl hmm that doesn't seem to change anything :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending different body structures and setting it directly in findOneAndUpdate() so it didn't work, where the structure is different.

The possible solution you can apply is to change the body of the request to look something like this:

```
"environment" : {
    "ePIMS" : value,
    "codeVersion" : value,
    "region" : value,
    "HCHC": {
        "instance" : value,
        "testEnv" : value
    }
}
```

Or you can put the two thing instance and testEnv out of HCHC if you want.

Either way make sure you have same structure if you are passing the body directly in the function.

Another solution

create a local variable to fix the structure and pass that in function like:

```js
router.put("/environments/:id", function(req, res){
  let body = req.body.environment
  let bodyData = {
    ePIMS: body.ePIMS,
    codeVersion: body.codeVersion,
    region: body.region,
    HCHC: {
      instance: body.instance,
      testEnv: body.testEnv
    }
  }
  Environment.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, bodyData, function(err, updatedEnvironment){
    if (err) {
      res.redirect("/environments");
    } else {
      res.redirect("/environments");
      //console.log(req.body.environment.instance)
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I've edited my question with the solution per your suggestion

Comment: Happy to help... you can explore deconstruct to make it cleaner - [reference](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects).

Answer (score 1):

this solution worked for me:

```
router.patch('/tasks/:id', async (req,res)=>{



    try{
        const task= await Task.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,req.body,{new:true,runValidators:true})

        if(!task)
        {
            res.status(404).send()
        }
    res.send(task)    
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})
```

however,my final solution included validation was inplementing update without using findByIdAndUpdate:

```
router.patch('/tasks/:id', async (req,res)=>{ 
//validate update operation  


const updates=Object.keys(req.body)
  const allowedUpdates= ['description','completed']
  const isInvalidOperation= updates.every((update)=>allowedUpdates.includes(update))




  if(!isInvalidOperation)
  {
     return res.status(400).send({error:'invalid updates'})
  }


  try{
      const task= await Task.findById(req.params.id)
      updates.forEach((update)=>task[update]=req.body[update])
      await task.save()

      if(!task)
      {
          res.status(404).send()
          }
      res.send(task)    
      }
      catch(e)
      {
          res.status(500).send()
      }
  })
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it working but really appreciate your help!